# maven-failsafe-plugin doesn't pick up testng tests

Tags: maven, integration-testing, testng, spring-test, maven-failsafe-plugin

I've got issue with maven-failsafe-plugin, when I'm specifying:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:testApplicationContext.xml"})
public class SomeIT extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
```

Plugin can't handle this test anymore.

Plugin configuration:

```
               <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you show the full pom file instead of excerpts?

Comment: 1) Do you have `org.testng:testng` configured as a `test` dependency for this project? 2) Do you have `junit:junit` configured as a dependency for this project? You need #1, but you do not necessarily need #2. See also [Selecting Providers](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/providers.html) for further details.